# Binary being analyzed must exist, iOS App Archive in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, three20

I'm trying to validate my App for App Store Submission, I've made an update to it. It was using Three20 before, though I'm not sure what version, probably 1.0.3. Now it's using 1.0.5 and I have rerun the python script that adds Three20 to an app with the --xcode-version=4 flag.

I have no linker errors, and it archives fine, but I get the following errors when I try to validate the archive for distribution:

[image]

I'm kind of at my wit's end, been dealing with linker errors all day, and general problems with Three20 and Xcode itself. Is there anything obvious I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The binary being analyzed must be an executable:

Check your build settings, because something's fishy.  Your Mach-O type should be set to executable:[image]

> Application failed codesign verification...

You must sign your executable with a Distribution certificate, you're most likely signed with a Development certificate, or not at all.

[image]

> The binary being analyzed must exist:

This is probably coming up because of issue number one.  Resolve the Mach-O type, and this should vanish instantly.

Comment: Thanks you were right on Mach-O for sure. It wasn't set to anything, needed to be set to "Executable". In regards to code-signing, I have been having lots of issues with this, so I suppose you're probably right in that regard as well.