# Cannot get passed the Validation stage of submitting app with iPhone 5 support

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

This is an old app that's been submitted many times without problems. I've modified the code and the info.plist to support iOS 6 and iPhone 5, but didn't change the build settings at all. I've checked the certificates and provisioning profiles, they are all sound. All adhoc builds ran just fine on our devices. I'm using Xcode 4.5.

I build without errors and it archives just fine.  It shows up in the Organizer. When I click Validate..., I click through just like normal, pick the right provisioning profile, but then it fails every time with the same three errors:

1. Unable to run the lipo command /Applications/Xcode.app...: can't open input file: ...(No such file or directory)
2. Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.
3. The binary being analyzed must exist: ...

I've tried the answers in the following question: [Binary being analyzed must exist, iOS App Archive in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11287713/binary-being-analyzed-must-exist-ios-app-archive-in-xcode) and my app checks out.

I suspect the problem is that I've included armv6, armv7 and armv7s as valid architectures, but I really have no idea what the problem is because this all worked in Xcode 4.4.

What do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can not build armv6 binaries using Xcode 4.5, the support for armv6 has been dropped by Apple.

It seems your errors are pretty much compounded after it reaches the first error so if you fix it so it builds for armv7 and armv7s then it should fix the rest of the errors (since it'll generate a valid binary if the script is fine with everything else and be able to be analysed)

Comment: What am I losing by dropping armv6?

Comment: armv6 is the original iPhone and iPhone 3G plus the first- and second-gen iPod touch. In other words, you’re not losing much.

Comment: armv6 is the architecture used in the iPhone/iPod Touch 2G and iPhone 3G so basically support for them devices within your app

Comment: If i do this i get: iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6